# Rails def for testing relations count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model for Location.  It contains:

```
has_many :woassets
has_many :workorders
has_many :contacts
has_many :worequests
has_many :costprojects
has_many :storerooms
has_many :employees
has_many :jobplans
has_many :woschedules
```

In a view, I don't want a `delete` button if the location has any records associated.  So, I'm doing this:

```
<% if location.workorders.count == 0 and location.woassets.count == 0 and location.contacts.count == 0 ...   %>
```

Is there a better way to put a `def` in the model and use it in the view?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Location 
  def has_assoc?
    [:rel1, :rel2, ...].any? { |r| send(r).present? }
  end
end
```

Or to look at all associations, rather than just a specific list:

```
def has_assoc?
  Location.reflections.keys.any? { |r| send(r).present? }
end
```

In the view:

```
<% if location.has_assoc? %>
```

Comment: Changed class to Location